# Animation API's for frames?

Tags: animation, java

I searched over Google, but I didn't find anything associated with my issues. However, I am able to use `SwingTimer` but it can do some basic things only, what I wan is some API that have multiple animation that I can select.

As it's none functional thing to my project(s), but it's a nice to have some animations to make the functional more comfortable with user.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use the [Timing Framework](https://java.net/projects/timingframework), this has more to do with the amount of library code I've built around it then it being superior to any of the other frameworks.

You may also wish to look at [Trident](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home), which has some nice mechanism for changing object properties and the [Universal Tween Engine](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/)

Comment: +1, I downloaded Universal Tween Engine and see what can I do with it. Thanks

Comment: Can you look at [this link](https://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/wiki/GetStarted), see the setter and getter for `Particle` class, I think the `setter's` methods are missing the parameter. I am I right?

Comment: Firstly, I've not had the chance to look at the tween engine (despite it looking really interesting), but yes, you are right.  Take a look at the comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use frames? If i'm not mistaken, that's a pretty outdated element. Personally i'd use something like Twitter Bootstrap, they have a "tabbed system" that is much much better.

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not related with `JavaScript`, it's for Java Application.

Comment: Ah, i'm embarrassed... that was the first time i've commented haha :) sorry about that!

Comment: +1,Get another up-vote and you'll be free to comment anywhere :)